# Which form of this verb is correct？

Tags: tense

> Tom often ____ newspaper in the library when he was at college.

a. Reads

b. Read

Both of them seem correct, but either one is wrong.

Comment: There is a missing article in front of "newspaper".

Answer (score 2):

> Tom often **read**(past tense) newspaper in the library when he
>   **was** at college.
>
> Tom often **reads** newspaper in the library when he **is**(Present tense) at
>   college.